# Segmentation fault driving me insane

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

It's a particle system I'm using. I wanted to make a cube out of particles but it now seems to be getting seg faults though it worked before. I am guessing it's the array but I cannot after 2 days of looking figure out the problem. GDB has been no help.

```
#include "particles.h"
using namespace std;

GLfloat texture1[10];
particle parts[50][50][50];
GLfloat angle = 1.0;

particles::particles()
{
    addTextures();
    cube();
}

particles::particles(int O)
{
    addTextures();
    cube();
}

void  particles::addTextures()
{
    texture1[0] = LoadTextureRAW("star_mask.bmp",256,256); //load texture
    texture1[1]  = LoadTextureRAW("star.bmp",256,256);
}

void particles::cube()
{
// for(int i =0; i<124999; i++)
// {
//  parts[i] = particle(1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
//  }

    float x=-5;
    float y=-5;
    float z=-5;

    for(int i =0 ; i <49 ;i++)
    {
        for(int k =0 ; k <49 ;k++)
        {
            for(int j =0 ; j <49 ;j++)
            {
            parts[i][k][j] = particle(i*0.01,k*0.01,j*0.01,1,1,1,0.09);
            }
        }
    }    
}

GLuint particles::LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int width,
                           int height )
{
    GLuint texture;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;

    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

    data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );

    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    glGenTextures(1, &texture );

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
        GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
        GL_LINEAR );
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGB, 
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    free( data );

    return texture;
}

void particles::FreeTexture( GLuint texture )
{
    glDeleteTextures( 1, &texture );
}

GLuint particles::LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int width, 
    int height);
void  particles::FreeTexture( GLuint texturez );

void  particles::square (void)
{
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1[0] );
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0);
    glVertex2d(1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0);
    glVertex2d(1.0,1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0);
    glVertex2d(-1.0,1.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: try commenting stuff out until it stops, if gbd wont give you a stack it is likely static init.

Comment: A little more information would be useful. For instance, how are you using the `particles` class? What is the last thing you do before the segv happens?

Comment: first step when you segfault: look at the backtrace..

Comment: Where exactly does it happen?

Comment: im using the particles class in a main class which i have never had trouble with before, the program fails just as i create the particles class

Comment: it seems to happen with the texture, which worked before

Comment: Post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Get rid of one of the constructors, they are duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

Your texture IDs are the wrong data type.  They should be `GLint`, but you're using `GLfloat`.

---

Another problem is that all your data appears to be held in global variables, but you're initializing it for each instance of the `particles` class.  So you'll be leaking textures and possibly have other unexpected behavior as well.

---

Another potential problem is that if you have a VBO bound, the data pointer in `gluBuild2DMipmaps` will be interpreted as an offset.  That could also cause trouble.

---

Besides all that, you should check the return values from `malloc`, `fopen`, and `fread`.  Right now you're ignoring errors, which could lead to a segmentation fault.

Comment: tried GLint it doesn't fix it though backtrace in gdb seems to bring me back to the texture again and again

GLfloat used to work fine

Comment: @strategos: I didn't really expect this to fix your segfault, but it was a problem with your code which could cause other problems (like using the wrong texture).  `GLfloat` can hold small integers, but larger integers could be rounded off to the available precision.  So it might be trouble when you add more textures, or use a different video card.

Comment: i went back and used a previous working version of my program, and seemed to get it working using a different texture creation method, so you were right, thanks for the help